# yes no confirm and window event

Tags: swing

I have following code snippet:

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(Bookstore.this, "Are you sure to quit?", "Confirm", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                // release connection resource
                if (bookstoreConnection != null) {
                    bookstoreConnection.closeConnection();
                }
                // JFrame handles close request based on the property
                // set by invoking the setDefaultCloseOperation(...)
                Bookstore.this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }                
        }
    });
```

and whenever i press [x] button at upper right corner the frame disappears regardless of whatever option i chose. In this case I want to know how to retain frame window if i choose NO option. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE)` as the default close operation on your JFrame subclass (I don't remember if this is the default if you don't explicitly add the `setDefaultCloseOperation(...)` with another value)

> DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE (defined in WindowConstants): Don't do anything;
>   require the program to handle the operation in the windowClosing
>   method of a registered WindowListener object.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation(int)

Comment: hi, if you don't use WindowListener object how can you close all resources like database connection before closing your application completely?

Comment: But aren't you using window listener?

Comment: yes i did use window listener to perform closing database connection resource and exit window if YES option is chosen but problem i'm facing now is if i choose NO option the application still working background but frame window disappears

Comment: @Final Illusion Anreas' suggestion works for me, if it doesn't for you there's some problem in your code, then it's time for a sscce